# C# multitarget platform dll

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I have problem with using C# dll on 3.5 and 4.5 platform. I have main app (unmanaged code) which use C# dll. And i need to target my dll to both 3.5 and 4.5 platforms.
For C# exe application i've used app.exe.config file like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I've tried to put it in dll folder, in main app folder with lib_name.config.dll and main_app.config.exe name. But it still doesn't work.
I should target single dll to both platform (so i can't use only 3.5 or 4.5 framework).
How can i use config file for dll?

Comment: A .config file still works for an unmanaged host program.  But it must have the name of that EXE and be stored in the same directory as that EXE.   Writing a custom CLR host is generally the best approach, it can ask for a specific CLR version with ICLRMetaHost::GetRuntime().

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the problems of managed code, I mean that if you used a "protocol/rules" to create a DLL, the applications using that DLL should understand that "protocol". So I don't think this is possible.

I always program the DLLs using C/C++ unmanaged (not .NET), so they are bytecode and unless you use specific features, they work from windows 95 to windows 8, on any programming language or platform, even .NET.

Regards,
Carles